# JavaScript function with parameter won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a function that would change the color of a row in a table when you click on it, there are many rows in this table.
I'm developing on Chrome (latest version) and it says that the function "selectme" is not defined.

My IDE is not signaling any errors (Dreamweaver CC)

```
<table>
<tr onClick="selectme('1')">
<td class="name">Relaxing Beauty - Ryan Astruld</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="selectme('2')">
<td class="name">Wheeving violins - John Lisbon</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="selectme('3')">
<td class="name">Grace -  David Parsons</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="selectme('4')">
<td class="name">Linkin Park - In The End (cover)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The javascript

```
function selectme(number)
{
    var selector = "#" + number
    $(selector).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
    selected = number;
}
```

Comment: whether `selectme` is defined within another function like a dom ready  handler

Comment: you havn't added id attribute in <tr>

Comment: Have you included the JS file that defines the function `selectme` in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks @ArunPJohny it was indeed the jQuery ready handler :)

Comment: that is the problem.... move it outside because inline event handler needs the function in global scope... since the function definition is within a dom ready handler it will be accessible only inside the dom ready handler method

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the element itself as argument, try

```
<table>
<tr onClick="selectme(this)">
<td class="name">Relaxing Beauty - Ryan Astruld</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="selectme(this)">
<td class="name">Wheeving violins - John Lisbon</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="selectme(this)">
<td class="name">Grace -  David Parsons</td>
</tr>
<tr onClick="selectme(this)">
<td class="name">Linkin Park - In The End (cover)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
 function selectme(elem){
      $(elem).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
    }
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vmb2q/)
OR You could bind the table tr click event, Say the tables id is `myTab`

```
$('#myTab tr').on('click',function(e){
    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
});
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkCET/)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
      <tr  id="1" onClick="selectme(this.id)">
        <td class="name">Relaxing Beauty - Ryan Astruld</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="2" onClick="selectme(this.id)">
        <td class="name">Wheeving violins - John Lisbon</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="3" onClick="selectme(this.id)">
        <td class="name">Grace -  David Parsons</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="4" onClick="selectme(this.id)">
        <td class="name">Linkin Park - In The End (cover)</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    function selectme(number)
    {

        $("#"+number).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
        selected = number;
    }
```

try this

Comment: I never knew you can pass attributes as parameters like that, this is super useful! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table12">
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Relaxing Beauty - Ryan Astruld</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Wheeving violins - John Lisbon</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Grace -  David Parsons</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="name">Linkin Park - In The End (cover)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#table12 tr').click(function(){
                    console.log(this);
                    $(this).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
                });
            });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :) The jQuery is already included, I just trimmed the code as much as possible to make it easier for people who want to help :)

Comment: I make my code like this to everything becomes clear as much as possible, I hope that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Inline event handlers are ugly and hard to maintain.

Why not try it unobtrusively?

```
$("table tr").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("blue");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/NBcLu/)

If you need to change the rows different colors, you could use data attributes, e.g.

```
<tr data-color="red">
  <td class="name">Relaxing Beauty - Ryan Astruld</td>
</tr>

$("table tr").on("click", function(){
    var color = $(this).data("color");
    $(this).toggleClass(color);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this

```
function selectme(number)
{
    var selector = "#" + number
    $(selector).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
    selected = number;
}
```

WITH

```
function selectme(number)
{
    var selector = "#" + number; //HERE YOU FORGOT SEMI-COLON
    $(selector).css("background-color", "rgb(3,135,255)");
    selected = number;
}
```

Also your HTML `onclick` will call the javascript function but in the function you have
`$(selector)` which should point to `id="1"` but no control on your page exists with the id 1.
So also add the `id="1"` on your td's

```
<td id="1" onclick="selectme('1');"></td>
```

and because you have the id on the TD now, you can reference it directly in the onclick part

```
<td id="1" onclick="selectme(this.id);"></td>
```

Comment: put an `alert("I'm HIT!");` within your selectme function, and see if it pops up. Make sure your function is within `<script language="javascript"> function selectme(number){...} </script>`, try putting it after the table load as well

Comment: Javascript is the default language for scripting if you use HTML5 (!DOCTYPE html). Plus, I just use the browser's console for errors and finding out where exactly the code crashed, I strongly recommend you do the same from now on.

Answer (score -1):

No semi-colon here:

```
var selector = "#" + number; <-- HERE
```

Comment: That is not the issue. It is not required to write a semicolon.